# How to save the entire contents of datagridview into the word document using office.word.interop.dll instead of spire.doc.dll?

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-word, office-interop

How to implement the logic of the 1st block of code using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll?
Now I am using third party dll(Spire.Doc.dll), instead of Spire.Doc.dll. I want to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll.
Please help me to implement this logic using the office word dll. Thanks

And in the 2nd block of codei tried to implement the logic og 1st block of code , i ahve achieved upto some extent however i coud not implement the complent logic of 1st block of code. it does not go well with the actual need. on button click event of more than once ( several times) all exported datagridview into word document are overlapping with each other so how to avoid the overlapping and save all tables properly(table right below the table)? please guide me to implement the above code logic.

All exported Datagridview content is getting merged in a single place (getting merged with each other) is there a way to save them in a well-organized way (recently exported table below the previously exported table)?
How to avoid overlapping? on button click event of more than once ( several times) all exported datagridview into word document are overlapping with each other so how to avoid the overlapping and save all tables properly(table right below the table)?

```
   // 1st block of code (using Spire.Doc.dll)
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using Spire.Doc;
 using Spire.Doc.Documents;
 using Spire.License;
 using Spire.Doc.Fields;

namespace Export_Datagridview
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public string filename;
    public string Reportfile_path;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("1");
        dt.Columns.Add("2");
        dt.Columns.Add("3");
        dt.Columns.Add("4");
        dt.Columns.Add("5");
        dt.Columns.Add("6");
        dt.Columns.Add("7");
        dt.Columns.Add("8");
        dt.Columns.Add("9");
        dt.Columns.Add("10");
        dt.Columns.Add("11");
        dt.Columns.Add("12");
        dt.Columns.Add("13");
        dt.Columns.Add("14");
        dt.Columns.Add("15");
        dt.Columns.Add("16");
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13",
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13",
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13",
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13",
   14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13",
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        export_datagridview();
    }
    private void export_datagridview()
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        string date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();  
        filename = Reportfile_path + "sample" + ".doc";
        Document document = new Document();
        try
        {
            document.LoadFromFile(filename, FileFormat.Doc);
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        int xx = 0, yy = 0, section_number = 0;
        Section section = new Section(document);
        Paragraph paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph = section.Paragraphs.Count > 0 ? section.Paragraphs[0] : section.AddParagraph();
        yy = document.Sections.Count;
        if (yy == 0)
        {
            section_number = yy;
            section = document.AddSection();
            section = document.Sections[section_number];
        }
        else
        {
            section_number = yy - 1;
            section = document.Sections[section_number];
        }
        xx = section.Tables.Count;

        if (xx == 5)
        {
            section_number++;
            section = document.AddSection();
            section = document.Sections[section_number];
        }
        else
        {
            section = document.Sections[section_number];
        }
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.AppendText("\t\t SOMETHING");
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.AppendText("Something\t\t:\tsomething");
        paragraph = section.AddParagraph();
        paragraph.AppendText("something\t\t:\tsomething");
        Add_Table(dataGridView1, filename, section);
        document.SaveToFile(filename, FileFormat.Doc);
    }
    private void Add_Table(DataGridView dGV, string filename, Section section)
    {
        Spire.Doc.Table table = section.AddTable();
        table.ResetCells(dGV.RowCount, dGV.ColumnCount);
        table.ResetCells(dGV.RowCount + 1, dGV.ColumnCount);
        // first row
        TableRow row = table.Rows[0];
        row.IsHeader = true;
        row.Height = 22;
        row.HeightType = TableRowHeightType.Exactly;
        row.RowFormat.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        for (int i = 0; i < dGV.ColumnCount; i++)
        {
            row.Cells[i].CellFormat.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Middle;
            Paragraph p = row.Cells[i].AddParagraph();
            p.Format.HorizontalAlignment = Spire.Doc.Documents.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            TextRange txtRange = p.AppendText(Convert.ToString(dGV.Columns[i].HeaderText));
            txtRange.CharacterFormat.Bold = true;
        }
        for (int r = 0; r < dGV.RowCount; r++)
        {
            TableRow dataRow = table.Rows[r + 1];
            dataRow.Height = 22;
            dataRow.HeightType = TableRowHeightType.Exactly;
            dataRow.RowFormat.BackColor = Color.Empty;
            for (int c = 0; c < dGV.ColumnCount; c++)
            {
                dataRow.Cells[c].CellFormat.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Middle;
                row.Cells[c].Width = 80;
                dataRow.Cells[c].Width = 80;

   dataRow.Cells[c].AddParagraph().AppendText(Convert.ToString(dGV.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value));
            }
        }
      }

   }
 }

      // 2nd block of code (using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll)

 ﻿using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;

 namespace Save_DataGridView_As_Word_Doc
 {
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string filename;
    public string filepath;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("1");
        dt.Columns.Add("2");
        dt.Columns.Add("3");
        dt.Columns.Add("4");
        dt.Columns.Add("5");
        dt.Columns.Add("6");
        dt.Columns.Add("7");
        dt.Columns.Add("8");
        dt.Columns.Add("9");
        dt.Columns.Add("10");
        dt.Columns.Add("11");
        dt.Columns.Add("12");
        dt.Columns.Add("13");
        dt.Columns.Add("14");
        dt.Columns.Add("15");
        dt.Columns.Add("16");
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
 14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
   14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
  14, "15", "16" });
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "1", 2, "3", "4", "5", 6, "7", "8", "9", 10, "11", "12", "13", 
   14, "15", "16" });

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        save_datagridview(dataGridView1, filename);
    }

    public void save_datagridview(DataGridView DGV, string filename)
    {
        string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
        string date = DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();
        filename = filepath + @"D:\datagridview" + ".docx";

        var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document();

        try
        {
            var originalDocument = application.Documents.Open(filename);
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        if (DGV.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            int RowCount = DGV.Rows.Count;
            int ColumnCount = DGV.Columns.Count;
            Object[,] DataArray = new object[RowCount + 1, ColumnCount + 1];
            int r = 0; for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
                for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
                {
                    DataArray[r, c] = DGV.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value;
                }
            }

            application.ActiveDocument.PageSetup.Orientation = 
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
            dynamic orange = application.ActiveDocument.Content.Application.Selection.Range;
            string otemp = "";
            for (r = 0; r <= RowCount - 1; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
                {
                    otemp = otemp + DataArray[r, c] + "\t";
                }
            }

            orange.Text = otemp;
            object Separator = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByTabs;
            object ApplyBorders = true;
            object AutoFit = true;
            object AutoFitBehavior = 
  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAutoFitBehavior.wdAutoFitContent;
            orange.ConvertToTable(ref Separator, ref RowCount, ref ColumnCount, Type.Missing, 
  Type.Missing, ref ApplyBorders, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 
  Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, ref AutoFit, ref AutoFitBehavior, Type.Missing);  

                orange.Select();
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Select();

   application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.AllowBreakAcrossPages = 0;
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows.Alignment = 0;
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.InsertRowsAbove(1);
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();

                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Bold = 1;
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Range.Font.Name = 
  "Tahoma";
                application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Range.Font.Size = 
  14;

            for (int c = 0; c <= ColumnCount - 1; c++)
            {
               application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Cell(1, c + 1).Range.Text 
   = dataGridView1.Columns[c].HeaderText;
            }
            application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].set_Style("Grid Table 4 - 
  Accent 5");
            application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Tables[1].Rows[1].Select();
            application.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.Cells.VerticalAlignment = 
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdCellVerticalAlignment.wdCellAlignVerticalCenter;

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in 
    application.ActiveDocument.Application.ActiveDocument.Sections)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range headerRange = 
   section.Headers[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;

                headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, 
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);

                headerRange.Text = "XYZ";
                headerRange.Font.Size = 18;
                headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 
   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
            }

            //object start = 0, end = 0;
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng1 = application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, 
   ref end);
            //Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range rng2 = application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, 
   ref end);
            //rng1.SetRange(rng1.End, rng1.End);
            //rng1.Text = "\t\t\t\t\t\t xyz\t :\t xyz ";
            //rng2.SetRange(rng2.End, rng2.End);
            //rng2.Text = "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t zyz\t :\t xyz ";

            application.ActiveDocument.Save();
            application.Quit();
            MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");

        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Before I start, it should be noted, as others have commented in the other questions you have posted, is that using “interop” is somewhat discouraged since there are other “free” third-party libraries that work just as well if not better. Example, interop is notoriously slow when dealing with large documents. However, I am also aware that in some cases you may not have an option. With that said, below is an example of adding tables to a Word document using interop.

In the current posted code, it is difficult to tell if you want to add the tables to a “new” document or add the tables to an existing document. The code below adds the tables to a “new” Word document.

Also, I recommend you break up the code to do certain things as this will make it easier to maintain and make changes. Example, having a method that simply “adds” the data from the grid to the table, without formatting the table. Then another method that formats the table and possibly another method to format the Word document. Mixing these things together in one method makes it difficult to maintain and make changes.

Given this, it would appear that a particular method could come in handy. This method would take two parameters… A `DataGridView` and a “Word Document.” This method would take the data from the given `DataGridView` and add the data to a new table and place that table to the end of the given Word Document.

As you may be aware of, dealing with ranges in Word can be cumbersome and placing the table in a particular paragraph will require extra work, however, it is doable. Because of this, the code below simply adds the table to the end of the document.

This method “Add_DGV_To_Doc” may look something like below. Following the code below, it first gets the range that is the end of the document… `Word.Range range = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range;` … a new paragraph will be added and the table will be placed in that new paragraph.

When creating the table to add to the Word document, an extra row is added for the header text. Then a new paragraph is added to the Word document. First a loop is started to set the header text for each column. Then the rows from the grid are added to the table. Lastly `FormatTable()` is called to format the new table. It appears your current posted code is doing unnecessary work by creating a string array then a string? All this appears unnecessary when you can simply read the data directly from the `DataGridView.`

```
private void Add_DGV_To_Doc(DataGridView dgv, Word.Document doc) {
  object mis = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
  object endOfDoc = "\\endofdoc";
  Word.Range range = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range;
  Word.Table table = doc.Tables.Add(range, dgv.RowCount + 1, dgv.ColumnCount, ref mis, ref mis);
  object prarRange = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref endOfDoc).Range;
  Word.Paragraph para = doc.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref prarRange);
  para.Range.Text = Environment.NewLine;
  string value;
  for (int col = 0; col < dgv.ColumnCount; col++) {
    table.Cell(1, col + 1).Range.Text = dgv.Columns[col].HeaderText;
  }
  int tableRow = 2;
  for (int row = 0; row < dgv.RowCount; row++) {
    if (!dgv.Rows[row].IsNewRow) {
      for (int col = 0; col < dgv.ColumnCount; col++) {
        value = "";
        if (dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value != null) {
          value = dgv.Rows[row].Cells[col].Value.ToString();
        }
        table.Cell(tableRow, col + 1).Range.Text = value;
      }
      tableRow++;
    }
  }
  FormatTable(table);
}
```

Next is a method that formats the table.

```
private void FormatTable(Word.Table table) {
  table.Rows[1].Range.Bold = 1;
  table.Range.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
  table.Rows[1].Range.Font.Size = 14;
  table.set_Style("Grid Table 4 - Accent 5");
  table.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
 }
```

Next is a method to format the Word document.

```
private void SetHeadersForSections(Word.Document doc) {
  foreach (Word.Section section in doc.Sections) {
    Word.Range headerRange = section.Headers[Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Range;
    headerRange.Fields.Add(headerRange, Word.WdFieldType.wdFieldPage);
    headerRange.Text = "XYZ";
    headerRange.Font.Size = 18;
    headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter;
  }
}
```

Also, in your current posted code, it is unwise to ignore exceptions as the following code does…

```
try
    {
        var originalDocument = application.Documents.Open(filename);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
```

Having an “empty” catch is basically ignoring the error and continuing. Minimum you should display “what” the error is and/or deal with the error before continuing. This is frowned upon in just about any environment, and will get negative marks in an academic environment.

Lastly, it should be noted that when you use “com” objects such as a “Word Application” and a “Word Document” … it is YOUR responsibility to “release” the com objects your code creates. Your code does not do this, therefore, if you run the code numerous times, you will probably see numerous “Microsoft Word” processes still running even after you quit the program.

Therefore, your code should release these “com” objects before the code exits to avoid this resource leak. This can be seen in the “finally” code section of the try/catch/finally block below.

Putting all this together, the code below adds two (2) different grids to a Word document, and saves the Word document when `button1` is clicked. The first `dataGridView1` is filled with sixteen (16) rows and columns. The second `datagridview2` is filled with ten (10) rows and columns.

```
public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  DataTable dt = GetTable(16, 16);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
  dt = GetTable(10, 10);
  dataGridView2.DataSource = dt;
}

private DataTable GetTable(int totCol, int totRow) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  for (int i = 0; i < totCol; i++) {
    dt.Columns.Add("H " + (i + 1).ToString());
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < totRow; i++) {
    dt.Rows.Add(GetRowArray(totCol));
  }
  return dt;
}

private object[] GetRowArray(int size) {
  object[] obj = new object[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    obj[i] = (i + 1).ToString();
  }
  return obj;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  save_datagridview(dataGridView1);
}

public void save_datagridview(DataGridView DGV) {
  string filename = @"D:\Test\datagridview.docx";
  Word.Application app = null;
  Word.Document doc = null;
  try {
    app = new Word.Application();
    //app.Visible = true;
    doc = app.Documents.Add();
    doc.PageSetup.Orientation = Word.WdOrientation.wdOrientLandscape;
    Add_DGV_To_Doc(dataGridView1, doc);
    Add_DGV_To_Doc(dataGridView2, doc);
    SetHeadersForSections(doc);
    doc.SaveAs2(filename);
    MessageBox.Show("Document created successfully !");
  }
  catch (Exception e) {
    MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + e.Message);
  }
  finally {
    if (doc != null) {
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(doc);
    }
    if (app != null) {
      app.Quit();
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, it really helped me a lot.   Please help me to implement this below code logic into the code one which you posted above.
string File_path; string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");                   string date=DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString(); Reportfile_path=File_path + "\\sample_doc\\"+date;  Directory.CreateDirectory(Reportfile_path);
filename = Reportfile_path + "sample" + ".doc";
Document document = new Document();
        try
        {
            document.LoadFromFile(filename, FileFormat.Doc);
        }
        catch
        {
        }

Comment: The flow of logic is 1) if File_path does not exist then create a new File_path and a word document and then save the datagridview into the word document 2) if File_path and word document exist with the "sample.doc" name then just export the datagridview itno it . i have already implemented this logic using spire.Doc.dll but i want to implement this logic using interop word dll so could you please guide me to achieve this .   THanks again

Comment: @The Techie… If you … _”already implemented this logic using spire”_ … then use the same logic. Checking if a folder exist or a document exist is usually done through the OS… so I am not sure where “spire” comes into play for this. I recommend researching on how to check if a folder exist or a file exist. There is plenty of info on this as it is not difficult. In addition, my answer demonstrates how to create and save a “new” Word document using interop. You may need to research how to open an existing Word file using interop.

Comment: Lastly, you should be aware that you can not use the `Date` properties as you are when defining a file path. Example, `string date=DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString();` is going to return something like “12/31/2019”… using this as a file path string is going to use the slash (/) as a folder and will most likely fail. Similarly, `string time = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");` will fail since the “:” character is invalid in a file name.

Comment: Ok sir got it, once again thank you so much and wish you a happy new year.